# WebSphere - JMS Connection Pool - Can the container test a jms connection?

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, websphere-7

**Issue:** Websphere connection pool will sometimes give a bad connection to the mq manager and a broken connection will occur. I rather not write any infrastructure code to test connections and do re-trys.

For JDBC in the WebSphere deployment console you can go under the "WebSphere Application Server data source properties" and set test connection and re-try. Can the same be done for JMS connection? Any container setting that would test a connection or re-try if a broken connection occurred.

**Websphere version: 7**

Answer (score 0):

We can manage the JMS Connection Properties via
**Resources** > **JMS** > Queue Conn. Fact. >  > [Additional Properties] > **Connection Pool**

set Reap time less then connection timeout (say 90)

It will help you out.

Comment: From WebSphere: Reap Time - Specifies the interval, in seconds, between runs of the pool maintenance thread.

Do you know if the pool maintenance thread test connections ?